# 'more than or equal to A and B'?

Tags: sentence-construction

- The height of A should be more than or equal to the thickness of B.
- The height of A should be more than or equal to the thickness of C.

I want to say these two things in one sentence. Can I say

- The height of A should be more than or equal to the thicknesses of B and C.
- The height of A should be more than or equal to the thicknesses of both B and C.
- The height of A should be more than or equal to the thickness of B, and more than or equal to the thickness of C.

I don't want it to be A≥B+C. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: The height of A should be more than or equal to the thickness of B **or** C.

Comment: @BillyKerr: one may (erroneously?) understand *(A≥B) OR (A≥C)*

Comment: To make the suggestion of @BillyKerr even clearer, you could add 'either' before 'B'.

Comment: @MichealHarvey yes, precisely!

Comment: Thank you very much. So 'thickness of either B or C'is correct? Is it (A≥B) AND (A≥C)?

Answer (score 1):

In maths A ≥ max(B,C) and writing that literally gives something like:

> The height of A should be *at least as much* as the greater thickeness of B and C.

You can use a contrapositive

> The height of A must not be less than the thickness of B or C.

Or you can explain in more open prose the situation.

> If the height of A is less than the thickness of either B or C then ... (describe the consequence)

But before using this, you should probably consider rephrasing.  Exactly how you rephrase might depend on what sort of document you are writing and for what kind of audience: Is it a technical specification or a personal essay?

Comment: Thank you. I was writing a technical document for internal use. A,B, and C are some kinds of parts, and part A is in between parts B and C.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is ambiguous because one can imagine than the minimum thickness is computed with B and C one above the other, i.e. A≥B+C.

Option 2 may be improved saying *The height of A should be **greater** or equal to the thicknesses of both B and C*.

Option 3 is correct but verbose.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will go with option 2.